# Touchpad on my laptop doesn't work after logging in to gnome

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad

I am using Ubuntu 10.10. I have my touchpad working till the gnome login screen. But once I login it doesn't work.

`tail /var/log/Xorg.0.log` gives me this error.

```
[    42.610] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    42.690] (--) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[    42.690] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    42.690] (II) No input driver/identifier specified (ignoring)
```

I guess I have to add the touchpad driver (synaptics) in Xorg configuration file. But any idea in which section and which syntax?

[EDIT]:
     Well, i have an aspire 4520. amd64x2 processor, synaptics touchpad
[EDIT]:
     Adding the config file in the given answer doesn't work.The problem stays in xmonad too.

Comment: Just for completeness: Which hardware do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to create the file:
`50-synaptics.conf`
in
`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`

The follows is mine:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "true"
        option "EmulateTwoFingerMinZ" "60"
        option "EmulateTwoFingerMinW" "10"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
EndSection
```

It will give you an emulation of two finger operation as well.

Hope this helps.